# Extracting specific bits from a 4 byte value into a new variable in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm very new to bit manipulations.

let's suppose I have a 32 bit value *myInput4ByteValue*.

From this 32 bit value I need to extract the bits 25 ..2

What would be the best approach here? 
My Idea is to split them into 3 bytes and copy the values there:

```
struct myOutput3ByteValue.
{
    uint8 FirstPart //  Bits 9..2  Least Significant 8 Bits from myInput4ByteValue.
    uint8 SecondPart // Bits 17 ..10
    uint8 ThirdPart  // Bits 25 ..18
}
```

I started with:

```
myOutput3ByteValue.FirstPart = (myInput4ByteValue & 0x3FC0) // Here I will the bits 9..2
myOutput3ByteValue.SecondPart = ...?                        //How to fill the rest?
```

I'm really not sure if I started correctly.
Suggestions would be helpful.

The reason why I split them into 3 bytes is because I will have an own 3 byte-type at the end with which I have to work with it.

Comment: (myInput4ByteValue & 0x3FC0)` would result in an integer with up to 2 bytes (0x3FC0) which wouldn't fit into `unit8`. You have to shift, e.g. `( myInput4ByteValue >>6) & 0xff`

Comment: What would be the eventual format you'd like to *have* those extracted bits in? That much is left somewhat unclear. You can "extract" the bits into another variable of 32bit size with a simple `& 0x3fffff8` (assuming you number bits starting with 0), and then...? That `struct` looks rather unwieldly, but that depends on what you'd *eventually* want to do with them...

Comment: There are semicolons missing from your question.

Comment: Probably bitfields are the most adequate. E.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bit-fields-c/ Be careful, as bitfields can behave a little different depending on the compiler used.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there wont' quite work. `0x3FC0` is a 16 bit int and you're assigning it to an 8 bit int, so it'll get truncated. You need to bitshift `<<` or `>>`. 
So bits 9..2 are:

```
FirstPart = (value >> 1); // No need to mask as bits 9+ will be truncated
SecondPart = (value >> 9); // Second set of 8 bits
```

Answer (score 0):

`myInput4ByteValue & 0x3FFFFFF` extracts the last 26 bits (the leftmost bit would be bit 25, as one usually starts counting from the right with bit 0).

`(myInput4ByteValue & 0x3FFFFFF) >> 2` shifts bits these two places to the right. This would hold your complete 23 bits.

If, however you want to have everything in 8-bit chunks, you could do:

```
myOutput3ByteValue.FirstPart = (myInput4ByteValue & 0x7F8) >> 2; // bits 9..2
myOutput3ByteValue.SecondPart = (myInput4ByteValue & 0x7F800) >> 10; // bits 17..10
myOutput3ByteValue.ThirdPart = (myInput4ByteValue & 0x3F80000) >> 18; // bits 25..18
```

Another approach, which could be much easier to read and maintain, is the use of bitfields.  See e.g. http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_bitfields .
Depending on whether individual bits or groups of bits have a particular meaning, you can give them their own name. If you align the structure nicely, you can simply copy the 32 bit input upon a variable with such a `struct` as type.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The reason why I need to split them into 3 parts I added in my question above right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a separate function that extracts no more than 8 bits starting from a given position from a number of the type `uint32_t`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t getbits( uint32_t x, unsigned p, unsigned n)
{
    const unsigned N = 8;

    n %= N + 1;

    return ( x >> p ) & ~( ~( uint32_t )0 << n );
}

int main(void) 
{
    uint32_t x = 0x12345678; 
    /*0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 */
    /*                           ^^^^^^^^^^  = 0x9E */
    struct myOutput3ByteValue
    {
        uint8_t FirstPart; //  Bits 9..2  Least Significant 8 Bits from myInput4ByteValue.
        uint8_t SecondPart; // Bits 17 ..10
        uint8_t ThirdPart;  // Bits 25 ..18
    } s =
    {
        .FirstPart = getbits( x, 2, 8 ),
        .SecondPart = getbits( x, 10, 8 ),
        .ThirdPart = getbits( x, 18, 8 )
    };      

    printf( "%x, %x, %x\n", s.FirstPart, s.SecondPart, s.ThirdPart );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9e,       15,       8d
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to put the extracted bits in a single UINT32 variable. What you need is simply to filter first 26 bits and shift them twice:

```
uint32 filteredValue = ( myInput4ByteValue & 0x03FFFFFF ) >> 2;
```

With the same logic, you can extract whatever you need and place them in any set of variable, according to the use you have to do wit the filtered bits.
You might want to define a general function performing the bits *extraction*:

```
uint32 filterValue( uint32 inValue, uint8 msb, uint8 lsb )
{
  uint32 retValue = inValue;

  // Let's just check that input params are ok
  if( msb < 32 && lsb <32 && msb >= lsb )
  {
    retValue = ( inValue & ( 0xFFFFFFFF >> ( 31 - msb ) >> lsb;
  }
  //else... input value unchanged. It doesn't make sense, but it's just an example..

  return retValue;
}
```

I personally wrote and tested it, and it works. **Note: it's just an example! Change it according to your requirements.**